# NodeJS prototype function don't wait of result

Tags: node.js

Hi i have written an export module for nodejs and use to other modules in there. Unfortunately the script don't wait for the last await

```
authentication.prototype.adAuth = async function(loginUser, loginPassword, User) {
    var authStatus = new Boolean();
    var query = User.where({
        username: loginUser
    }).populate("provider").populate("roles");
    await query.findOne(async function(err, user) {
        console.log("first await");
        if (err) {
            authStatus = false;
        }
        if (user) {
            if (user.provider.authModule === "activedirectory") {
                var configAD = {
                    url: user.provider.optionFields.adURL,
                    baseDN: user.provider.optionFields.adUserBaseDN,
                    username: user.provider.optionFields.adUserDN,
                    password: user.provider.optionFields.adUserPassword
                };
                var ad = new ActiveDirectory(configAD);
                await ad.authenticate(loginUser, loginPassword, function(err, auth) {
                    console.log("second await");
                    if (err) authStatus = false;
                    authentication.prototype.setSession(user);
                    console.log(auth);
                    authStatus = true;
                });
            } else {
                authStatus = false;
            }
        } else {
            authStatus = false;
        }
    });
    return authStatus;
};
```

first await
POST /login 500 314.923 ms - 2497
second await
true

I don't know why the ad.authenticate doesn't wait of the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, because the function you are calling does not return a Promise, it uses the older style - *callbacks*.

You need to turn the callback function into a Promise. Try something like this:

```js
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ad.authenticate(loginUser, loginPassword, function(err, auth) {
        console.log("second await");
        if (err) authStatus = false;
        authentication.prototype.setSession(user);
        console.log(auth);
        authStatus = true;
        resolve();
    });
})
```

As a general note, there's a lot of places where `authStatus = false;`, this suggests that you should write this piece in a more functional style. Mixing Promises and static values has a tendency to cause bugs. But that snippet above *should* fix your problem.

Comment: same problem. What do you mean with in more functional way?

ok when i set both functions in await new Promise it works.

Comment: I don't have enough information to help you with the problem then. Sorry. By functional, I mean to use Promise chains, rather than await. Await was an extension to Promises that helped tidy up some scenarios, it lends itself to a more OOP style, which can cause bugs. Again, I don't know enough about your problem, but I suggest that `authentication.prototype.adAuth` should _resolve_ if auth was successful, and _reject_ with an error if it wasn't. Using chains (i.e. then's) is more functional and reduces side-effects. It's a much longer discussion than what I can write here I'm afraid.